# Alternative Solutions for Terence Tao's Analysis I (4ed) Excercise 3.4.6 and further reading suggestions.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Does anyone have any alternative solutions for this exercise. I'm self studying this book and I don't find many answers online, and don't even know if mine is correct, I find it a bit long. I would like to see how anyone else reasons through this exercise. I find it curious that you can get every function $Y^X$  from $\{0,1\}^X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Also, does anyone have a list of equivalences of axioms of ZFC? For example I also know that (given extensionality) replacement + empty set= specification. Im curious what other equivalences there are.

Thanks beforehand to anyone who responds :)

**Exercise 3.4.6**

(i) Prove Lemma 3.4.10. (Hint: start with the set $\{0,1\}^X$ and apply the replacement axiom, replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.)

(ii) Conversely, show that Axiom 3.11 can be deduced the preceding axioms of set theory if one accepts Lemma 3.4.10 as an axiom. (This may help explain why we refer to Axiom 3.11 as the "power set axiom".)

**Axioms and Lemmas referenced**

**Axiom 3.11** (Power set axiom). Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$, thus

$$f \in Y^X \iff f \text{ is a function with domain } X \text{ and codomain } Y$$

**Lemma 3.4.10** Let $X$ be a set. Then the set
$$
\{Y: Y \text { is a subset of } X\}
$$
is a set. That is to say, there exists a set $Z$ such that
$$
Y \in Z \Longleftrightarrow Y \subseteq X
$$
for all objects $Y$.

Also assume all other usual ZFC axioms appart from choice, i.e union, replacement, specification, etc.

**My attempted solution:**

(i) Let $Y \subset X$, we define the following function $f_Y:X\to \{0,1\}$

$$f_Y(x)=\begin{cases}
    1 &\text{if }x \in Y\\
    0 &\text{if }x \notin Y\\
\end{cases}$$

Which is well defined, as $Y\cup Y^c=X$. We claim that $Y=f^{-1}_Y(\{1\})$. We prove this by double inclusion. First we show that $Y\subset f^{-1}_Y(\{1\})$. Indeed

\begin{align*}
    x \in Y &\implies f_Y(x) \in f_Y(Y)\\
    &\iff f_Y(x) \in \{1\}\\
    &\iff x \in f_Y^{-1}(\{1\}).\\
\end{align*}

Now we show that $f^{-1}_Y(\{1\}) \subset Y$. Indeed

\begin{align*}
    x \in f_Y^{-1}(\{1\}) &\iff f_Y(x) \in \{1\}\\
    &\iff f_Y(x) =1\\
    &\iff x \in Y\\
\end{align*}

Where $f_Y(x) =1 \implies  x \in Y$, because $x \notin Y \implies f(x)\neq 1$ and the codomain is only $\{0,1\}$. The converse holds by definition. We have proven that

$$\forall Y \subset X, \exists f \in \{0,1\}^X, Y=f^{-1}( \{1\}).$$

Namely $f=f_Y$. Furthermore, $f_Y$ is unique. Indeed, let $f_Y':X\to \{0,1\}$ such that $ Y=f'^{-1}_Y(\{1\})$. Then

\begin{align*}
    x \in Y & \iff x \in f'^{-1}_Y( \{1\})\\
            & \iff f'_Y(x) \in \{1\}\\
            & \iff f'_Y(x) =1\\
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$ x \in Y \iff f'_Y(x) =1,$$

which implies $x \notin Y \iff f'_Y(x) \neq 1$, and since the codomain is only $\{0,1\}$,

$$x \notin Y \iff f'_Y(x) =0.$$

Thus $f_Y=f'_Y$. Finally we have proven that

$$\forall Y \subset X, \exists! f \in \{0,1\}^X, Y=f^{-1}( \{1\}).$$

Namely $f=f_Y$. Conversely, if $f \in \{0,1\}^X$, there is a unique $Y \subset X$ such that $Y=f^{-1}(\{1\})$. Indeed, simply let $Y =f^{-1}(\{1\})$, this $Y$ is clearly a subset of $X$ (by definition). Furthermore this $Y$ is unique because of extensionality. Therefore

$$\forall f \in \{0,1\}^X, \exists! Y \subset X, Y=f^{-1}(\{1\}).$$

Namely $Y=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ itself. Therefore let $P(f,Y)$ be the property $Y=f^{-1}(\{1\})$. We have proven that for each $f \in \{0,1\}^X$ this is true for exactly one $Y \subset X$. Using the axiom of replacement, there exists the set

$$\mathcal{P}(X)=\{Y:Y=f^{-1}(\{1\}) \text{ for some } f \in \{0,1\}^X\}.$$

Which contains every subset of $X$, because $\forall Y \subset X, \exists! f \in \{0,1\}^X, Y=f^{-1}( \{1\}).$ And contains only subsets of $X$ because $\forall f \in \{0,1\}^X, \exists! Y \subset X, Y=f^{-1}(\{1\}).$ Thus $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: A hint for (ii): Use the power set of $X\times Y$ and identify functions $f\in Y^X$ with their graphs.